# Run "rhc alias" in Java

Tags: java, dns, openshift, cname, openshift-client-tools

Using the Java SDK, I have my application that I need to input domain name from the UI. However my question is if it is possible for `rhc alias` to be called from Java code?

```
rhc alias proxy www.xyz.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using the OpenShift Java Client to add an alias to your account: https://github.com/openshift/openshift-java-client/